# matplotlib plot multiple 2 point lines, not joined up

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to print a series of ticks on a scatter plot, the pairs of x and y points are stored in two nx2 arrays.  Instead of small ticks between the pairs of points, it is printing lines between all the points.  Do I need to create n lines?

```
xs.round(2)
Out[212]: 
array([[ 555.59,  557.17],
       [ 867.64,  869.  ],
       [ 581.95,  583.25],
       [ 822.08,  823.47],
       [ 198.46,  199.91],
       [ 887.29,  888.84],
       [ 308.68,  310.06],
       [ 340.1 ,  341.52],
       [ 351.68,  353.21],
       [ 789.45,  790.89]])

ys.round(2)
Out[213]: 
array([[ 737.55,  738.78],
       [ 404.7 ,  406.17],
       [   7.17,    8.69],
       [ 276.72,  278.16],
       [  84.71,   86.1 ],
       [ 311.89,  313.14],
       [ 615.63,  617.08],
       [ 653.9 ,  655.32],
       [  76.33,   77.62],
       [ 858.54,  859.93]])
plt.plot(xs, ys)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is indeed to plot `n` lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs  =np.array([[ 555.59,  557.17],
       [ 867.64,  869.  ],
       [ 581.95,  583.25],
       [ 822.08,  823.47],
       [ 198.46,  199.91],
       [ 887.29,  888.84],
       [ 308.68,  310.06],
       [ 340.1 ,  341.52],
       [ 351.68,  353.21],
       [ 789.45,  790.89]])

ys = np.array([[ 737.55,  738.78],
       [ 404.7 ,  406.17],
       [   7.17,    8.69],
       [ 276.72,  278.16],
       [  84.71,   86.1 ],
       [ 311.89,  313.14],
       [ 615.63,  617.08],
       [ 653.9 ,  655.32],
       [  76.33,   77.62],
       [ 858.54,  859.93]])

for (x,y) in zip(xs,ys):
    plt.plot(x,y, color="crimson")

plt.show()
```

[image]

If `n` is very large, a more efficient solution would be to use a single `LineCollection` to show all lines. The advantage is that this can be drawn faster, since only a single collection is used instead of `n` line plots.

```
# data as above.
seq = np.concatenate((xs[:,:,np.newaxis],ys[:,:,np.newaxis]), axis=2)
c= matplotlib.collections.LineCollection(seq)
plt.gca().add_collection(c)
plt.gca().autoscale()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: To animate it, so the ticks move with their markers, how do I update the x and y points in the LineCollection?

Comment: Via `c.set_offsets(new_seq)`.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.  That's not working for me in the animation.  So I've used the plt.plot(..) approach.  That's better, fast enough, but how do I remove the previous ticks?  They are heading markers to accompany circle markers on the scatter plot.

Comment: I can't know why it is not working for you. For line plots you would call `line.set_data(xs[i],ys[i])` to set the data of `line` to the `i` th coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the end points of the arrays `xs` and `ys`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([[ 555.59,  557.17],
       [ 867.64,  869.  ],
       [ 581.95,  583.25],
       [ 822.08,  823.47],
       [ 198.46,  199.91],
       [ 887.29,  888.84],
       [ 308.68,  310.06],
       [ 340.1 ,  341.52],
       [ 351.68,  353.21],
       [ 789.45,  790.89]])


ys = np.array([[ 737.55,  738.78],
       [ 404.7 ,  406.17],
       [   7.17,    8.69],
       [ 276.72,  278.16],
       [  84.71,   86.1 ],
       [ 311.89,  313.14],
       [ 615.63,  617.08],
       [ 653.9 ,  655.32],
       [  76.33,   77.62],
       [ 858.54,  859.93]])

for segment in zip(xs, ys):
    plt.plot(segment)

plt.show()
```

[image]